# Why is psql not asking for db password when using pg_service.conf

Tags: postgresql

I've opened an SSH tunnel to connect to a remote server as follows:

```sh
$ ssh -f -N -L 5433:127.0.0.1:5432 username@servername
```

This tunnel has been precisely opened as follows (as shown by `ps aux | grep ssh`):

```sh
ssh -f -N -L 5433:127.0.0.1:5432 username@servername
```

I do have a `~/.pg_service.conf` with:

```yml
[my-pg-service]
    host=127.0.0.1
    port=5433
    dbname=mydatabase
    user=pguser

# just append the .pgpass file here:
[my-pg-service-2]
    host=127.0.0.1
    port=5433
    dbname=mydatabase
    user=pguser
    passfile=~/.pgpass
```

When running:

```sh
$ psql service=my-pg-service
```

it currently (and surprisingly) connects without asking for the database password! (may it be it's stored in a sort of cache because I already used it prior to that command?)

But when using `psql service=my-pg-service-2` it actually asks for the database password.
I hoped it would behave the opposite way!

my `~/.pgpass` (`chmod 0600`) file looks like:

```yml
#hostname:port:database:username:password

# Remote pg database on server servername when using an SSH tunnel (5433)
127.0.0.1:5433:mydatabase:pguser:8+k3&4d2ihs1=&gp!*y)62xoh+^^z$&*ino!66jj()(yw@o36
```

Please note that this command is also asking for the database password:

```sh
$ psql -d postgres://pguser@localhost:5433/mydatabase
```

But this one is not:

```sh
$ psql -d postgres://pguser@127.0.0.1:5433/mydatabase
```

(I only changed `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`).

And this is precisely because there is no such line starting with `localhost` in the `.pgpass` file:

```yml
localhost:5433:mydatabase:pguser:8+k3&4d2ihs1=&gp!*y)62xoh+^^z$&*ino!66jj()(yw@o36
```

If I add this line, `psql` connects without prompting for a password in both previous cases, but I still have the issue with the pg service, e.g. when specifying `passfile=~/.pgpass` it asks for a password, and when not, it doesn't.

Can someone please explain this behaviour and what I did wrong?
May this be linked to the server side configuration which is too broad?

Just in case, the database is dockerized on the remote server. It uses the [official postgis docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/) (`13:3.2`) which presents these default characteristics:

```
$ docker run \
  --rm \
  --name postgis \
  -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=changeme \
  -d postgis/postgis:13-3.2

$ docker exec -it postgis bash -c "tail -n 21 /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf"

# CAUTION: Configuring the system for local "trust" authentication
# allows any local user to connect as any PostgreSQL user, including
# the database superuser.  If you do not trust all your local users,
# use another authentication method.

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

host all all all md5
```

OS: Ubuntu 21.10
PG: 14

Doc:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-pgservice.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: You shouldn't share a password here

Comment: Don't worry, it's a random string picked on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is easy to explain.

If you don't specify `passfile`, the password is taken from `.pgpass` in your home directory, so you are not prompted for a password.

If you specify `passfile=~/.pgpass`, PostgreSQL cannot find the file, because it does not understand the tilde (which is a shell feature, and you are not using a shell), so it prompts you for the password.

Comment: Ah perfect, it didn't work either with `passfile=${HOME}/.pgpass` but it did when using the full path: `passfile=/home/username/.pgpass`!

Answer (score 2):

The service file does not understand the tilde to represent your home directory.  It takes it as a literal character in the filename.  So that file doesn't exist, you have essentially unset that file. (without a warning, for some reason).